# strcat simulation in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *str1="beautiful";
    char *str2="place";
    xstrcat(str1,str2);
}

xstrcat(char *s1,char *s2)
{

    char *temp;
    temp=s1;

    while(*s1!='\0')
    {
        s1++;
    }
    while(*s2!='\0')
    {
        s1++;
        *s1=*s2;
        s2++;
    }
    s1++;
    *s1='\0';
    printf("\n%s",temp);
}
```

Error output:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x000000000040055d in xstrcat (s1=0x400696 "place", s2=0x400696 "place")
    at strcat.c:23
    23  *s1=*s2;

I am not able to write in that memory. Can anyone please tell why i am getting this error. ?

Comment: because you don't own that memory.

Comment: Must be many duplicates for this...

Comment: http://c-faq.com/malloc/malloc2.html

Comment: @apprentice - Those kind of improvements should be posted as an *answer*.  Fixing up the *question* kind of defeats [the purpose of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about) ... ;-) Plus the context is lost, so none of the responses/comments make sense any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str1` is a string literal it is undefined behavior to write to that location. It would be valid to create and write to `str1` if it was defined like this:

```
char str1[100] = "beautiful";
```

Comment: why is it store it as const without we declared??

Comment: @user1762571 Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2589974/1708801